# Is protobuf a good choice for external microservice? By external microservice I mean some service that is exposed as a RESTful endpoint

Tags: rest, protocol-buffers, microservices

If protobuf is used as a data serialization for external microservice that serves a RESTful endpoint, the protobuf message needs to converted back to JSON message, which will increase the overall message response time.

I know protobuf is good for communication between internal services, but is it good for external services as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An external API is : whatever the external API is. If that external API is gRPC, then protobuf is a *great* choice, as that is *virtually always* what gRPC uses (you need to really try hard to use something other than protobuf with gRPC). gRPC is not ubiquitous, but nor is it uncommon for inter-business APIs (especially if one end is Google, obviously).

Having to translate a message between different shapes (whether that be entirely different formats, or different payloads in the same format) is fairly normal, assuming you're not simple a pass-thru proxy, so: having to decode and encode isn't a major shocker. If you can make *at least one of those* steps have the size and speed benefits of protobuf: then great.